# Magento 2 - How to read the values in etc/config.xml?

Tags: magento2, configuration, best-practice

How to define and read the values in `etc/config.xml` in a custom module?
What is the best practice to use it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Put it in context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot read the values directly from `etc/config.xml`.
I mean, you can, but there is no point in reading directly from there since the values may be overwritten from the stores->configuration section that makes the value from `config.xml` useless.
Instead you can read from the global merged config and if the value is not overwritten in the configuration section you get the value from `config.xml`.

And you can do that by adding a dependency to your class that needs to read the config value like this:

namespace Your\Namespace\Here;

```
class YourClassName
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
        ....
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        ....
    ) {
        ....
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        ....
    }
}
```

Then you can read the config value like this

```
$path = 'path/to/value';
$value = $this->scopeConfig->getValue($path, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Or, if it's a yes/no flag and you want to get a `true/false` value you can do it like this:

```
$flag = $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag($path, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

`$path` represents all the tags concatenated by slash (`/`) up to your value (similar to M1).

To define them in `config.xml` you need to add this in your file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default><--! reserved word -->
        <section><!-- anything goes here -->
            <group><!-- anything goes here -->
                <value1>1</value1><!-- anything goes here -->
                <value2>some text</value2><!-- anything goes here -->
            </group>
        </section>
    </default>
</config>
```

Using the code above,

```
$value = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('section/group/value1', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

will return `1` and

```
$value = $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag('section/group/value1', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

will return `true`.