# Magento 2. Get value from config inside email template

Tags: magento2, configuration, email-templates

I wish to retrieve value from `config.xml` inside email template. Is it possible? If so how? This is what I tried without success

```
 {{config path='path/to/value'}}
```

Comment: Review this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139148/magento-2-how-to-read-the-values-in-etc-config-xml

Comment: @DhadukMitesh not really what I'm aiming for. I want a more direct way.

Comment: If you use `{{template config_path="path/to/value"}}` then what issue is occurred?

Comment: EDIT. Does not work Output: Error filtering template: Email template 'value' is not defined.

Comment: I found some comment from this link, https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3891

Comment: Check your path is proper or not.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Path be correct

Comment: @KeyurShah Please your link in an answer. As it is correct.

Comment: Done :) @vitoriodachef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [github comment](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3891) I can see that Magento limit the some config value to access on frontend.

"Magento not allow show all configuration data on frontend. You can use only limited list of config that described in `\Magento\Email\Model\Source\Variables::__construct`"

Answer (score 5):

I think you can add your own allowed paths in your own `Vendor/CustomModule/etc/di.xml` like it is done in `vendor/magento/module-variable/etc/di.xml:12` :

```
<type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configPaths" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="web" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="web/unsecure/base_url" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="web/secure/base_url" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            </item>
            ...
```

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
{{template config_path="path/to/value"}}
```

Comment: Does not work
Error filtering template: Email template 'value' is not defined.